# How to bind events to element generated by ajax

Tags: ajax, yii, jquery

I am using `RenderPartial` to generate `CListView` and all the contents generated properly and good pagination is working fine too. But when I added my custom JS to elements generated by the `CListview` it works fine for the the fist page content but when i use pagination and click to page 2 then the JS binding fails.

Is there any other way to bind custom event to elements generated in YII `CListview` I had tried using live, and on nothing work for me here is my js file.

I think I have to call my function on every ajax load in but how can I achieve in yii

This is the script I am using to update ratings on server with button click and this the element for which these forms and buttons are defined are generated by `CListview` in yii

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('form[id^="rating_formup_"]').each(function() {
        $(this).live('click', function() {
            alert("hi");
            var profileid=  $(this).find('#profile_id').attr('value');
            var userid=  $(this).find('#user_id').attr('value');  
            console.log(userid);
            var data = new Object();
            data.profile_id=profileid;
            data.user_id=userid;
            data.liked="Liked";
            $.post('profile_rating_ajax.php', data, handleAjaxResponse);
            return false;     
       });
    });
});
```

Comment: `.live` has been deprecated as of jQuery 1.7. Use `.on` as the replacement

Comment: i tried on and live both didnt seems to work

Comment: If you're partially rendering, be sure to postprocess the HTML. 4th parameter of [renderPartial](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController/#renderPartial-detail) should be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The $.each method will loop only on existing elements, so the live binder will never see the ajax-generated content.

Why don't you try it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('form[id^="rating_formup_"]').live('click', function() {
      alert("hi");
      var profileid=  $(this).find('#profile_id').attr('value');
      var userid=  $(this).find('#user_id').attr('value');  
      console.log(userid);
      var data = new Object();
      data.profile_id=profileid;
      data.user_id=userid;
      data.liked="Liked";
      $.post('profile_rating_ajax.php', data, handleAjaxResponse);
      return false;     
   });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also try [CGridView.afterAjaxUpdate](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView#afterAjaxUpdate-detail):

```
'afterAjaxUpdate' => 'js:applyEventHandlers'
```

Comment: After a couple of false starts, I'd like to make it really clear that "applyEventHandlers(id,data)" is a function that you have to write. It's not a built-in function for CGridView objects that you can use to rebind event handlers to enclosed elements.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by two ways:

1. Use 'onclick' html definitions for every item that is going to receive that event, and when generating the element, pass the id of the $data to the js function. For example, inside the 'view' page:

   ```
   echo CHtml::htmlButton('click me', array('onclick'=>'myFunction('.$data->id.')');
   ```
2. Bind event handlers to 'body' as the framework does. They'll survive after ajax updates:

   ```
   $('body').on('click','#myUniqueId',funcion(){...});
   ```