# Yii, Multiple Grid views on same page

Tags: php, ajax, gridview, yii

I am facing some problems with multiple grid views on single page.

At start when I open a single grid view in a jQueryUI tab, the pagination on it works properly. Now when I open a new tab with new grid view in it using an ajax call the pagination on new grid view works fine but pagination links on first grid view renders/opens a new page rather than updating the grid view with ajax, as if pager links are normal links

I am not getting the exact problem or cause behind this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem lays in the ajax loaded content, the click events on the content will not be registered, you will need .on('click') instead of .click()

the problem is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10948475/how-to-bind-events-to-element-generated-by-ajax-in-yii)

Comment: events get registered properly. when I open a second grid view, all pager links for it works perfectly. But pager links on first (previously opened) grid view (which are properly working till I open new grid) stops working and act like if they are normal links.

Comment: secondly, where should I change this '.click' to .on? the problem is with grid view.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. Upon clicking the pagination or the sorting the links get opened in new page.

If you notice, you will find that the url doesn't have `&ajax=id-of-the-grid` value in it, where id is the id of the grid you want to update.

What solved the problem for me was to add the script jquery.yiigridview.js file in the view,
and reinitializing the view manually.

Here is a working piece of code that solved the annoying problem for me.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Project/assets/dd5f9a70/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    /*<![CDATA[*/
    jQuery(function($) {
    jQuery('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();

    jQuery('body').tooltip({"selector":"[data-toggle=tooltip]"});

    jQuery('#project-grid').yiiGridView(
{'ajaxUpdate':['project-grid'],
'ajaxVar':'ajax',
'pagerClass':'pagination',
'loadingClass':'grid-view-loading',
'filterClass':'filters',
'tableClass':'table table-stats table-striped table-sortable',
'selectableRows':1,
'enableHistory':false,
'updateSelector':'{page}, {sort}',
'filterSelector':'{filter}',
'url':'/Project/index.php/realTime/AjaxUpdateProjectGrid',
'pageVar':'Project_page',
'afterAjaxUpdate':function() {
                jQuery('.popover').remove();
                jQuery('[data-toggle=popover]').popover();
                jQuery('.tooltip').remove();
                jQuery('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip();
            }});
    });
    /*]]>*/

    </script>
```

Hope it helps someone. 
Thanks,
Maxx